# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier @OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I keep getting `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier` when trying to create an object. My classes are as follows:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserDetail userDetail;
}

public class UserDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;
}

@Service
public class UserDetailService {

   @Autowired
   private UserDetailRepository userDetailRepository;

   public void create(UserDetail userDetail) {
      userDetailRepository.saveAndFlush(userDetail);
   }
}
```

And when I try to create a `UserDetail`:

```
String userId = "user";
User user = userService.findByUserId(userId);
UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
userDetail.setUserId(userId);
userDetail.setUser(user);
user.setUserDetail(userDetail);
userDetailService.create(userDetail);
```

I get the exception

**Stack trace of the exception:**

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:68)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.generateEntityKey(AbstractSessionImpl.java:327)
at org.hibernate.type.OneToOneType.isNull(OneToOneType.java:110)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:500)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:366)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:178)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:211)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:444)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:249)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:317)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.merge(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:410)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:421)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:401)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
at com.my.services.RepositoryUserDetailService.create(RepositoryUserDetailService.java:17)
at com.my.services.RepositoryUserDetailServiceTest.testCreate(RepositoryUserDetailServiceTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 29):

I was stuck with a very similar problem. It seems that saving the `UserDetails` first, while there are also changes to the User (`user.setUserDetail(userDetail)`), requires an explicitly set cascade mode.

Adding the `CascadeType.ALL` to the `UserDetails @OneToOne` definition fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed my problem. After migrating from hibernate 4 to 5 I was getting the very same exception.

Comment: I was faced with the same issue in hibernate 5.4.15 and Spring data jpa 2.2.7. Adding CascadeType.ALL was the solution.

Comment: But why? Why should I put `CascadeType.All`?

Comment: @JinKwon I haven't seen the Hibernate code, so I can only make an educated guess: 
Since both entities are modified, they will both end up in the pre-save checks and as there is no cascade definition, the assumption is made that they both must be in a state where they can be saved individually. Just that they can't: 'User' references a 'UserDetail' which doesn't have an ID yet.
From a database perspective, this is nonsense. From an object layer perspective, this is... nit-picky.

Comment: @chn4 Thank you for your comment. Seems related to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13866

Answer (score 2):

In my case it works by setting the relationship to null. Looks like it loads it anyway using the @Id.

```
UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
userDetail.setUserId(userId);
userDetailService.create(userDetail);
```

Comment: This does work for me but I have no idea the reason. Can you explain the reason?

Comment: That's absolutely insance solution, but it does work with Spring Boot 2..6.7!

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to upgrade from 4.2.x version of Hibernate to 4.3.11. The exception does not show up anymore, looks like a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, save parent before, add parent to relationship field of child (child haven't id), after save child (id get from Parent Entity)
references:
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

```
@Entity
public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    private long profileId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    // ...
}



@Test
public void whenSaveDerivedIdEntity_thenOk() {        
    User user = new User();
    session.save(user);
       
    UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
    profile.setUser(user);
    session.save(profile);

    assertThat(profile.getProfileId()).isEqualTo(user.getUserId());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I've managed to solve it.
Try this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional = false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

From what I've been able to find out, when persisting `UserDetail`, Hibernate takes a different code path and an underlying `merge()` call is being made instead of `persist()`, as you have stated in your issue. One fix could be adding `CascadeType.MERGE`.

Please have in mind that this fix does have the effect that the underlying `User` could be updated.

Another possible fix could be to use [Spring Data Persistable interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html), that gives you control of determining if an object is a new object or not, making the repository save method take the correct path (merge or persist).

Sources:

- https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2020/09/23/spring-boot-2-2-x-and-onetoone-null-identifier/
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20181
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13413?attachmentOrder=asc

Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74500104/11667138

Answer (score 0):

My current fix is by implementing the Persistable-interface as Kashan Nadeem pointed out. Here the relevant code:

```
@Override
public boolean isNew() {
  return id == null;
}
```