# OneToOne-association produces error on 5.4.0+ when using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

We have Spring Boot application using a OneToOne annotation and PostgreSQL.

Owning class:

```
@Table(name = "PAYMENT")
public class PaymentDO  {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "PAYMENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long paymentId;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "payment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private PaymentBatchJobDO paymentBatchJob;

}
```

Owned class:

```
@Table(name = "PAYMENT_BATCH_JOB")
public class PaymentBatchJobDO {

  @Id
  @Column(name="PAYMENT_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long paymentId;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PAYMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PAYMENT_ID")
  private PaymentDO payment;

}
```

What I want to do is saving a PaymentDO and then add a PaymentBatchJobDO to it (using Spring's JpaRepository). Strangely when trying to save the PaymentBatchJobDO this fails.

The PaymentBatchJobDO is an optional child of PaymentDO. The relation is done using 'shared primary key'. This means PaymentBatchJobDO's paymentId-field becomes same value as PaymentDO's paymentId-field.

Until Hibernate core 5.3.* that worked perfecty but with 5.4.* I get following error:

```
2020-02-14 11:08:20.631  INFO 67291 — [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-02-14 11:08:20.636  INFO 67291 — [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Payment onlyPaymentDO{paymentId=1945, paymentBatchJob=null, amountTotal=12.00}
PaymentPaymentDO{paymentId=1945, paymentBatchJob=null, amountTotal=12.00}
2020-02-14 11:08:21.108 ERROR 67291 — [           main] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure           : HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.generateEntityKey(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:523) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.OneToOneType.isNull(OneToOneType.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:488) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:776) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:763) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.swisscom.billing.testhibernate.PaymentsTxService.addPaymentBatchJob(PaymentsTxService.java:53) ~[main/:na]
at com.swisscom.billing.testhibernate.PaymentsTxService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4919717e.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.swisscom.billing.testhibernate.PaymentsTxService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$604ba717.addPaymentBatchJob(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at com.swisscom.billing.testhibernate.StartupBean.onApplicationEvent(StartupBean.java:35) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
```

If I use a H2 database the error does not occur.

Configuration:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

There are different ways to implement a OneToOne relationship. If I change to the (probably more typical):
Owned class:

```
@MapsId
private PaymentDO payment;
```

I get following error:

```
2020-02-14 11:25:41.048 ERROR 74847 — [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column paymentbat0_.payment_payment_id does not exist
Position: 8
2020-02-14 11:25:41.054  INFO 74847 — [           main] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2045) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2007) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2401) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2384) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4350) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:570) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:538) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1182) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1171) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2809) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2746) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3340) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3312) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:281) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.swisscom.billing.testhibernate.StartupBean.onApplicationEvent(StartupBean.java:28) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
```

--> paymentbat0_.payment_payment_id does not exist!

If I set `hibernate.id.disable_delayed_identity_inserts=true` the error does not change in any way.

I tried using hibernate-core in version 5.4.0.CR1 & 2 as well but error occurs there identically. Furthermore I noticed that when I update to hibernate-core 5.4.0 I get newer versions of hibernate-commons-annotations, javaassist an org.jboss:jandex. If I these back to the state used for hibernate-core 5.3.* error is still the same. Thus the error originates definitely in the hibernate-core 5.4.* version.

Since it is a Spring Application I use SimpleJpaRepository's save() method. As I have seen now this method calls EntityManager.merge() (do notice: not persist()) although the object to save is new. When using hibernate-core on versions 5.3.* this properly saved the object.
The fact that EntityManager.merge() is called is, that the ID-field is already filled out. This is a result of the 'shared primary key' used for the one-to-one relation.

My question is thus: Have the rules using EntityManager.merge changed? Was it just luck the old code worked or should EntityManager.merge work lenient enough to check that the object is not yet saved and persist it properly? (In Hibernate's Session.merge-Javadoc I read: "If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent instance.")

As a workaround I called EntityManager.persist() instead of SimpleJpaRepository's save() which helped. Nevertheless it is bad practice to mix both APIs.

Comment: And what if you try to save the `PaymentBatchJobDO` first and then the `PaymentDO` ?

Comment: I have to save PaymentDO first and at a later stage PaymentBatchJobDO. (Please see my updates above I got a bit further on...)

Comment: OK but can you save `PaymentBatchJobDO` before associating it with `PaymentDO` ?

Comment: @Dimitri This is something I do not want: The PaymentBatchJobDO shall use the same primary key as PaymentDO (known as 'shared primary key'). This means, a PaymentDO can live without a PaymentBatchJobDO but a PaymentBatchJobDO not without a PaymentDO.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13413?attachmentOrder=asc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I've managed to solve it.
Try this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PAYMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PAYMENT_ID")
private PaymentDO payment;
```

From what I've been able to find out, when persisting `PaymentBatchJob`, Hibernate takes a different code path and an underlying `merge()` call is being made instead of `persist()`, as you have stated in your issue. One fix could be adding `CascadeType.MERGE`.

Please have in mind that this fix does have the effect that the underlying `Payment` could be updated.

Another possible fix could be to use [Spring Data Persistable interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html), that gives you control of determining if an object is a new object or not, making the repository save method take the correct path (merge or persist).

Sources:

- https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2020/09/23/spring-boot-2-2-x-and-onetoone-null-identifier/
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20181
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13413?attachmentOrder=asc